# In what scenario could two particles cause fluorescence to each other?

Tags: electrons, radiation, x-rays, microscopy

Ni $K$ X-rays have higher energies than Fe $K$
X-rays, thus,  Ni $K$ X-rays cause Fe $K$ X-ray
fluorescence, meaning that there are more Fe $K$
X-rays than expected and the Fe
concentration appears higher.

The opposite could happen in a situation involving Fe and Cr. Fe $K$ X-rays would cause Cr $K$ X-ray fluorescence because there are more Cr $K$
X-rays than expected and the Fe
concentration will appear lower.

**In what situation could two atoms (not necessarily any of the ones gives in this example) cause fluorescence to each other, implying that corrections both ways would be needed?**

In my understanding, for an atom to cause fluorescence to the other, its $K_\alpha$ value must be higher than the other element's $K_{edge}$, so for both elements to mutually induce fluorescence would require for these values to either change or for some energy-level related event (that I am unaware of) to happen. **Could this in some way be connected to $L_{\alpha, \beta , \gamma}$ transitions, which results in the electron's final state to be $n=2$ and not the ground level (represented by the $K$ transitions)?**

---

*The examples above were taken from a lecture presenting the $K_\alpha$ and $K_{edge}$ values  (in KeV)  for the elements below:*

Cr:     $K_\alpha$ - 5.415      $K_{edge}$ - 5.989

Fe:     $K_\alpha$ - 6.404     $K_{edge}$ - 7.111

Ni:     $K_\alpha$ - 7.478      $K_{edge}$ - 8.332

Comment: What are the units of measurement of these "$K$" values?

Comment: Oh, my bad, it is KeV.

Comment: The last sentence seems incomplete.